# Output block in particular region from custom module drupal 7

Tags: blocks

I have a custom module that spits out a form using the drupal form API. What I'd like to do is output a block (a custom menu) in a particular region of the page (using block regions would be the best way I'm guessing.) As of now, the block renders in the top left everytime. How can I output the menu block in a particular region of the page?

```
function client_menu(){

 $items=array();

 $items['campaign']=array(

   'title'=>'Campaign Manager',
   'description'=>'Area for clients to manage their campaigns',
   'page callback'=>'drupal_get_form',
   'page arguments'=>array('client_campaign'),
   'access arguments'=>array('access client administration'),
   'type'=>MENU_NORMAL_ITEM   
 );

 return $items;

}

function client_campaign(){

$block = module_invoke('menu', 'block_view', 'menu-client-admin');
print render($block);

//a bunch of form API stuff...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you creating a standard block which returns your form? Currently you have a page callback (http://yoursite.com/campaign), and you are injecting this into a block ...

Here is some sample code that could help you further:

```
function client_block_info()
{
    $blocks = array();

    $blocks['client_campaign'] = array(
        'info' => t('Area for clients to manage their campaigns'),
        'title' => t('Campaign Manager'),
        'region' => 'content', // Your desired region, can be edited in administration screen
        'status' => 1,
    );

    return $blocks;
}

function client_block_view($delta = '')
{
    $block = array();

    switch ($delta) {
        case 'client_campaign' :
            $block['content'] = client_block_content();
            break;
    }

    return $block;
}

function client_block_content()
{
    return drupal_get_form('client_campaign');
}

function client_campaign($form, &$form_state)
{
    // Build your form

    return $form
}
```